# Can an answered question be deleted?

Tags: discussion

Well, obviously the answer is yes, because a question I took trouble answering, complete with a complex mock-up (and which the OP accepted) has been deleted.

Because it's been deleted I no longer have any links to it in my profile, so I can't give a link, although I expect high-rep members can see what I'm referring to.

Is this on? I thought that once a question had been answered it couldn't be deleted? I'm not sure it was "too localised", so I'd be surprised if it was closed and deleted. What happened to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well moderators can delete any question, but this was a self delete. Users with 10k rep can also *vote* to delete, but that's very rare on UX.

You can delete your own question if:

- It is totally unanswered
- Or if it has no upvoted answers (wasn't aware of this one either until recently)
- It hasn't been closed within the last two days (to allow for reopening)

I agree that your answer shouldn't have been deleted since you put effort into it. It's partly my bad as well, I really should have closed it earlier since it's Not a Real Question (quite hard to tell what he's asking IMO). I've undeleted the post and closed it.

Comment: Thanks. It hasn't reappeared yet, though. When it does, I'll edit it so it's clearer (as it appears that I did understand what the questioner wanted!)

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/is-it-bad-to-have-3-levels-of-divs-on-the-z-axis . Should have popped back into your profile. It's not on the front page because it has a score of -4 (posts with a score -4 or lower don't show on the front page). You can see it on the /questions page/tab though.

Comment: Great. I didn't know about the -4 thing either! I've had a go at the question, so hopefully it's now worthy of consideration.